# How can I debug `Error while fetching server API version` when running docker?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

#### Context

I am running [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), and trying to run a sample Docker container using Airflow's [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.4/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html). I am testing using `docker-compose` and deploying to Kubernetes (EKS). Whenever I run my task, I am receiving the Error: `ERROR - Error while fetching server API version`. The erros happens both on `docker-compose` as well as EKS (kubernetes).

Comment: did you try to add the `api_version="auto"` argument as appear in the documentation?https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.4/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html

Comment: Hi @ItayB  =. ) I have tried setting that but I still got the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your Airflow Docker container is trying to launch a worker on the same Docker machine where it is running. To do so, you need to give Airflow's container special permissions and, as you said, acces to the Docker socket. This is called Docker In Docker (DIND). There are more than one way to do it. In [this tutorial](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/) there are 3 different ways explained. It also depends on where those containers are run: Kubernetes, Docker machines, external services (like GitLab or GitHub), etc.

Comment: Hi @emi I have followed the tutorial but seems like mounting did not solve my issue or I am doing it wrong. Am i mounting the right way?

Comment: The answer has not resolved my issue but indeed gave me a better clue

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70100729/1259982) for a reference to an alternate method.