# Running chmod on docker socket has no effect

Tags: bash, unix, permissions, chmod, user-permissions

Following advice from [Airflow: DockerOperator fails with Permission Denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499661/airflow-dockeroperator-fails-with-permission-denied-error) I executed

`sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`

However, it has no effect on permissions of my docker socket, and I still get a Permissions Denied error when trying to run DockerOperator that uses this socket.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  40 15 Jun 13:35 docker.sock -> /Users/mpw/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

I know that changing permission of docker socket is a suboptimal practice. However, I do not understand why the `chmod` has no effect on the docker socket file & symlink and would be very grateful if someone could point me to an explanation.

Comment: Can you run following command as `npw` (not `root`) : `ls -lL /var/run/docker.sock` ?

Comment: Permissions are not applicable to symlinks. When you run `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` it's actually changing the permissions of the file the symlink refers to. So I would expect `ls -l /Users/mpw/.docker/run/docker.sock` to show the expected permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Kurtis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4276647/kurtis-rader): this command actually changes permissions of the file that the symlink refers to; permission changes are not applicable to symlinks themselves.

Source of my operator failing must have been somewhere else, because the socket itself had it's permissions set to 777 after executing the command.